Calculations for date
There is a scenario where some notifications are thrown. As a user, I will be setting a password. There will be an expiry date for the password that has been set. Say it is going to expire on 14/07/2024.
There should be a check that the password is going to expire within 90 days from the current date. Based on that a notification saying it is going to expire in 90 days will be shown. And once it reaches the expiry date there should be a grace period that has been given to the user for password updated from the date of expiry.
Let's say a grace period of 30 days is provided from the date of expiration again for the user to update the password. Based on this again a notification will be sent. I have tried for 90 day period and it worked but for taking 30 days of grace period from the date of expiration I am not sure how to fetch it.
public static void main(String ars[]) throws Exception{
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            
            int expiryCount =90;
            Date date = formatter.parse("12-04-2024");
            Instant expiry = date.toInstant();
            Duration d = Duration.between(Instant.now(), expiry);
            int days = (int)d.toDays();
            System.out.println( d.toDays());
            
            if (days <= expiryCount) {
                System.out.println("Days are less!!!!");
                
                if (days < 0) {
                    System.out.println("its a grace time!!!");
                    int graceCount = 30;
                    
                    Date dt = formatter.parse("16-04-2024");
                    Instant today = dt.toInstant();
                    //Instant today = Instant.now(); 
                    Instant graceDate = today.plus(graceCount, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
                    System.out.println("graceDate::: " + graceDate);
                    Duration gracePeriod =  Duration.between(today, graceDate);
                    int diff = (int)gracePeriod.toDays();
                    System.out.println("diff::: " + diff);
                    
                    if(diff <= graceCount) {
                        System.out.println("You are in grace period!!!");
                    }
                    if(diff < 0) {
                        System.out.println("you made us to force you!!!!");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("More days left!!");
            }
             
        }
            catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
        }


please stop using the old date/time classes like Date, TimeStamp, Calendar, ... these were replaced by classes of the java.time package - see documentation

Surely the grace period represents an addition to the 90 days? e.g. DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu");LocalDate.parse("12-04-2024", formatter).plusDays(90+30);

Obviously that calculation would be done separately

In your update (days < 0) is always true

I suggest: LocalDate.parse() for parsing a date string. LocalDate.plusDays() for finding first the expiration date and next the date where the grace period ends. LocalDate.isBefore() or .isAfter() for determining whether today’s date falls in either period.

tl;dr
if
(
    LocalDate
    .of( 2024 , Month.JULY , 14 )  // Expiry.
    .plusDays( 30 )                // Grace period.
    .isAfter( LocalDate.now() )    // Test for today not yet past grace. Better to specify time zone explicitly rather than rely implicitly on JVM’s current default time zone.
)
{ … }

Avoid legacy date-time classes
You are using terribly flawed date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern java.time classes defined in JSR 310.
LocalDate
For date-only value, use LocalDate class.
LocalDate expiry = LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.JULY , 14 ) ;

Determine today’s date.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;

Elapsed days
Calculate elapsed time as a number of days.
long daysUntilExpiry = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( today , expiry ) ;
if ( daysUntilExpiry > 90 ) { … } 

Period
Calculate the deadline by allowing a thirty-day grace period.
Period grace = Period.ofDays( 30 ) ;
LocalDate deadline = expiry.plus( grace ) ;


Perform such calculation using the java.time package.
Code may look like this:
Date date = formatter.parse("12-04-2024"); // just for compatibility with OP's code
Instant expiry = date.toInstant();
Duration d = Duration.between(Instant.now(), expiry);
System.out.println( d.toDays() );

The above prints the number of days until expiry. Use that value to take further decisions and actions. This part can look like so:
int daysRemaining = d.toDays();
if (daysRemaining <= -30) {
    // grace period is over. Force the user immediately
} else if (daysRemaining <= 0) {
    // grace period has started. Remind the user
} else if (daysRemaining < 90) {
    // Less than three months to go. What to do here?
} else {
    // more than three months to go. What to do here?
}


thanks for the time you invested. But I guess you misunderstood my question on 30 days period. This 30days should be calculated once password reset date is expired.

Even then you do not need to perform the same calculation again. Just reuse the same value.

I recommend that you use LocalDate for a date and DateTimeFormatter for parsing it. Avoid Date, it had design problems and has been outdated for 10 years.

It is easier to say 'avoid java.util.Date' than to actually do it. There are just so many APIs that use it - often you are forced to.

@queeg Thanks for reporting back. Many APIs that I use have now been supplemented with methods accepting and returning modern types. I you use one where all you can get from it is an old-fashioned Date, we need to accept that, obviously; you are doing the wise thing when converting that Date to a modern Instant first thing (you may also perform further conversions from there). There’s still no reason to use SimpleDateFormat, a genuine and notorious troublemaker of a class.

Duration is the wrong class here. That class represents a span of time on the scale of hours-minutes-seconds. But the question is about dates, not hours. You are introducing complexity without benefit.

You consider it overhead complexity. I call it a feature, since I can use the same set of classes and similar style of code for spans of time ranging from sub seconds to years. There is a computational deviation between Duration and Period but in the above use case it can be neglected.

but in the above use case it can be neglected. It cannot. Duration.toDays() assumes a day is always 24 hours. Because of summer time (DST) and other time anomalies days may be 23 hours, 25 hours or other lengths. Depending on exact requirements your calculation will give incorrect results in corner cases. Also using Period or simply ChronoUnit.DAYS would have told the reader from the outset that you are interested in days(-months-years) rather than hours-minutes-seconds, so would help reading.

Yes I acknowledge the computations reveal different results. Now for a password reminder, I do not care to give or take an hour.

I Just simplified your code and it works fine.
But it will be better if you use new Date-Time.
  public static void main(String ars[]) throws Exception {
      SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
      final long expiryCount = 30;

      Date stratDate = formatter.parse("12-01-2024"); // password update time
      System.out.println("End date ::: " + stratDate);

      long days = getDifferenceDays(stratDate, new Date());
      System.out.println("Days passed ::: " + days);

      if (days <= expiryCount) {
        System.out.println("Password not expired");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Password expired");
      }
  }

  public static long getDifferenceDays(Date d1, Date d2) {
      long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
      return TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  }

Please think about this first solve your code flow.
I think this will be like this.

Save a time that is password update time.
Duration of (current-time & update-time).
Check duration and generate notification.
Update your code to new time api.


Kindly check now the code now I updated in this question. That is the exact problem facing now for grace period if I check like that everyday again 30 days will get added to current date. So grace period never ends

Outdated and also wrong. I recommend you stay far away from SimpleDateFormat and Date. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, exclusively. TimeUnit.DAYS and therefore your calculation assume that a day is always 24 hours, which does not hold true. It can be 23 or 25 hours or some other length.

I'm agree with you about out dated but it's not defers if you have a right way for thinking about your problem. For example when you are working about time it's better choose a way that you don't get negative duration or time deference.
In this way you can upgrade your code in any time.

There is no reason to be using SimpleDateFormat & Date in 2024. These terribly flawed classes were years ago supplanted by the modern java.time classes defined in JSR 310.

After multiple tries and inputs got here. This is what I expected as output.
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    try {
        
        int expiryCount =90;
        Date date = formatter.parse("12-03-2024");
        Instant expiry = date.toInstant();
        Duration d = Duration.between(Instant.now(), expiry);
        int days = (int)d.toDays();
        System.out.println( d.toDays());
        
        if (days <= expiryCount) {
            System.out.println("Days are less!!!!");
            
            if (days < 0) {
                System.out.println("its a grace time!!!");
                int graceCount = 30;
                Instant result = expiry.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                        .plusDays(1).with(LocalTime.of(23,59,59,expiry.getNano()))
                        .toInstant();

                Instant today = Instant.now(); 
                Instant graceDate = result.plus(graceCount, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
                System.out.println("graceDate::: " + graceDate);
                Duration gracePeriod =  Duration.between(today, graceDate);
                int diff = (int)gracePeriod.toDays();
                System.out.println("diff::: " + diff);
                
                if(diff <= graceCount) {
                    System.out.println("You are in grace period!!!");
                }
                if(diff < 0) {
                    System.out.println("you made us to force you!!!!");
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("More days left!!");
        }
         
    }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    


Suggesting the use of SimpleDateFormat and Date in 2024 is poor advice. Mixing them with their replacements (java.time) is even worse advice.

Answers in Stack Overflow are expected to offer some explanation. This site is meant to be more than a code-snippet library.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
